# Retrieve List of Roles related to User using spatie/laravel-fractal, Permissions works perfectly

Tags: laravel, permissions, roles, laravel-permission, thephpleague-fractal

I followed this topic on getting list of roles and permissions through user model using spatie/laravel-permission but none are engaging on my kind of concern.
Want to retrieve list of roles related to user using spatie/laravel-fractal through `$user->roles` and `$user->permissions` just like zizaco/entrust when I call `fractal($user, new UserTransformer)->parseIncludes(['roles', 'permissions'])->toArray();`, used `$this->collection($user->roles, new RoleTranformer)` in UserTranformer.php but throws `Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError`. I am building an API project using laravel 5.7 and spatie/laravel-permission and spatie/laravel-fractal so trying to organise json response using relations.

Comment: What are the versions of your `PHP` and `spatie/laravel-fractal`

Comment: using `php: 7.2` and `spatie/laravel-fractal: ^5.5` but problem is with `spatie/laravel-permission` cannot fetch collection when using `$user->roles`

Comment: Got the problem, recommends use of `\Spatie\Permission\Models\{Role, Permission}` rather than custom `\App\Models\{Role, Permission}`. to be namespaced in `Role::transform()`.